# How to select different columns as a list?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

I have a database like this:

```
column1 column2 column3
15      21      19
17      12      13
15      24      14
```

Now I want to get a list of every single number like this:

```
x    value
1    15
2    21
3    19
4    17
5    12
...
```

Thank you!

Comment: Whoever nominated this for reopening, how about posting a comment explaining on what basis? It's both unclear and a gimme-teh-codez question. The only changes made in the edit were the addition of tags.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT (@auto:=@auto+1) AS num, val
FROM (SELECT column1 AS val
      FROM tableA
      UNION
      SELECT column2 AS val
      FROM tableA
      UNION
      SELECT column3 AS val
      FROM tableA
    ) AS A, (SELECT @auto:=0) AS B
```